# Where/how can I execute this function contained in models.py?

Tags: python, django

I need to execute the get_result() function for every Bet instance

**models.py**

```
class Bet(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='bets', blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  match = models.ForeignKey(Match, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='bets') 
  team1_score = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
  team2_score = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
  result = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, null=True)

  def get_result(self):
    if (self.match.get_endscore() == self.match.team1) and (self.team1_score > self.team2_score):
      self.result = 3
    elif (self.match.get_endscore() == self.match.team2) and (self.team2_score > self.team1_score):
      self.result = 3
    elif (self.match.get_endscore() == "tie") and (self.team1_score == self.team2_score):
      self.result = 3
    elif (self.match.team1_score == self.team1_score) and (self.match.team2_score == self.team2_score):
      self.result = 6
    else: 
      self.result = 0
    return self.result
```

I thought this function out:

```
range = Bet.objects.all()
for bet in range:
  bet.get_result()
  bet.save()
```

The part that I'm not entirely sure about is where to execute it, or if I can insert the function into a script and with an additional tool execute it a given time (such as an asynchronous process for example).

I'm fairly new at this and I may not have enough expertise to solve it, I'm not even sure if it can be done.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a good candidate for a [management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-management-commands/).

In your app folder, create the folder structure `management/commands` and add a file `my_command.py` (you should pick a better name that reflects what your command actually does).

In that file would be something like the following:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand

class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        # your code here
```

You would then be able to run it as `python manage.py mycommand`.